# Cleaning Up Query Strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, friendly-url

This is more of an open question. What is your opinion on query strings in a URL? While creating sites in ASP.NET MVC you spend a lot of time thinking about and crafting clean URLs only for them to be shattered the first time you have to use query strings, especially on a search form.

For example I recently did a fairly simple search form with half a dozen text field and two or three lists of checkboxes and selects. This produced the query string below when submitted

```
countrylcid=2057&State=England&StateId=46&Where=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Tags=&Keywords=&Types
=1&Types=0&Types=2&Types=3&Types=4&Types=5&Costs=0.0-9.99&Costs=10.00-29.99&Costs=30.00-59.99&Costs=60.00-10000.00
```

Beautiful I think you'll agree. Half the fields had no information in them and the list inputs are very verbose indeed.

A while ago I implemented a simple solution to this for paging which produced a url such as

```
www.yourdomain.com/browse/filter-on/page-1/perpage-50/
```

This used a catchall route to grab what is essentially a replacement query string after the filter-on portion. Works quite well but breaks down when doing form submissions.

Id be keen to hear what other solutions people have come up with? There are lots of articles on clean urls but are aimed at asp.net developers creating basic restful urls which MVC has covered. I am half considering diving into model binding to produce a proper solution along those lines. With the above convention the large query string could be rewritten as:

```
filter-on/countrylcid-2057/state-England/stateId-46/types-{1,0,2,3,4,5}/costs-{0.0-9.99,10.00-29.99,30.00-59.99,60.00-10000.00}/
```

Is this worth the effort?

Thanks,

Comment: "a fairly simple search form with half a dozen text field and two or three lists of checkboxes and selects." Google's search form is "fairly simple." This one is complicated. It's OK if it produces a complicated URI, under the circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal view is that where users are likely to want to either bookmark or pass on URLs to other people then a nice, clean "friendly" URL is the way to go. Aesthetically they are much nicer. For simple pagination and ordering then a re-written URL is a good idea.

However, for pages that have a *large number* of temporary, dynamic fields (such as a search) then I think the humble query string is fine. Like wise for pages whose contents are likely to change *significantly* given the exact same URL in the future. In these cases, URLs with query strings are fine and, perhaps, even preferable as they at least indicate to the observant user that the page is dynamic. However, in these cases it may be better to use form POST variables, anyway, that way visitors are not tempted to "fiddle" with the values.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said, a URL implies a hierarchy that is semantic. Whether true today or not, the ancestry is directories and people still think of it as such. That's why you have controller/action/id. Likewise, to me a querystring implies options or queries.

Personally, I think a rewritten URL is best when you can't tell if there's an interpreter behind it -- maybe it's just a generated HTML file?

So however you choose to do it (and it's a pain on the client in a search form -- I'd say more trouble than it's worth), I'd support you doing it for hierarchies.

E.g. /Search/Country/State/City

but once you start getting into prices and types, or otherwise having to preface a "directory" with the type of value (e.g. /prices=50.00/ or worse, with an array), then that's where you've lost me.

In fact, if all elements are filled in, then all you've really done is taken the querystring, replaced "&" with "/", and combined your arrays into a single field.

If you're going to be writing the javascript anyways, why don't you just loop through the form elements and:

1. Remove the empty ones, cleaning up the querystring from the "&price_low=&price_high=&" sorts of things.
2. Combine multiple values into an array structure

But then submit as a querystring.

James

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the values of the different fields available in the FormsCollection anyway on post?

Comment: Yes they are this is simply how they appear in the address bar. Also for search it is preferable to use GET for search form so they can be bookmarked.

Comment: Good point. I guess you could compile the querystrings into some kind of structure you could more easily reference? –